# how to create array object using integer variable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fill an array object as like below using integer variable.

```
for(i=1; i<=2; i++)

arr[i].push({i:(100 * i)})
```

Expected result is:

```
arr = [{ 1:100,2:200},{1:100,2:200}]
```

Problem is, array created as like below

arr = [{i:100,i:200},{i:100,i:200}]

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: `arr.push` not `arr[i].push`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push to arr instead of arr[i].
Also, you can't use a variable as a key in json directly.

```
var arr = []; 
for(i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    var b = {}; 
    b[i] = 100*i;
    arr.push({[i]:(i*100)});    
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes this is working for me.